# Progress Bar Not Updating on JPanel

Tags: java

I have researched this one within Stackoverflow and have found many useful tidbits. However; my code does not seem to work.
I have a JFrame (Race) that has 2 JPanels. One panel (ControlPanel) carries the buttons that I use (Start, Reset, Exit). The other (Track) has several ProgressBars.

My start button's code on the ControlPanel is as such:

```
private void btnStartActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){                                         
    Track myTrack = new Track();
    Thread myThread = new Thread(myTrack);
    myThread.start();
}
```

Track extends JPanel and implements Runnable and has the following methods (for the Red ProressBar):

```
@Override                                         /|\
public void run() { // started by myThread.start() |
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
        updateBar(i);
        try{
            Thread.sleep(50);
        } catch (InterruptedException e){

        }
    }
}

public void updateBar(final int newVal) {

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            pbRed.setValue(newVal);
            pbRed.setStringPainted(true);
            System.out.println(newVal);
        }
    });
}
```

When btnStart is clicked, the output to the console dsiplays newVal. However; the progress bar does not update.
Thoughts?

*** Added Code ****

Main

```
package myrace;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

    public class MyRace {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Race rRace = new Race();
            rRace.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            rRace.setSize(450, 330);
            rRace.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
```

Track

```
package myrace;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Track extends JPanel implements Runnable {

    public Track() {
        initComponents();
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
            updateBar(i);
            try{
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException e){

            }
        }
    }

    public void updateBar(final int newVal) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                pbRed.setValue(newVal);
                pbRed.setStringPainted(true);
                System.out.println(newVal);
            }
        });
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        pbRed = new javax.swing.JProgressBar();
        lblRed = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(485, 185));
        setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(485, 185));
        setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(485, 185));

        pbRed.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
        pbRed.setToolTipText("");
        pbRed.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(426, 25));
        pbRed.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(426, 25));
        pbRed.setName(""); 
        pbRed.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(426, 25));
        pbRed.setRequestFocusEnabled(false);
        pbRed.setStringPainted(true);

        lblRed.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12)); 
        lblRed.setText("Red");
        lblRed.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(44, 15));
        lblRed.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(44, 15));
        lblRed.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(44, 15));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(5, 5, 5)
                .addComponent(lblRed, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(5, 5, 5)
                .addComponent(pbRed, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(5, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(35, 35, 35)
                        .addComponent(pbRed, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(40, 40, 40)
                        .addComponent(lblRed, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap(125, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
    }// </editor-fold>                        


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblRed;
    private javax.swing.JProgressBar pbRed;
    // End of variables declaration                   

}
```

Race

```
package myrace;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Race extends JFrame {

    public Race() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")                 
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        controlPanel1 = new myrace.ControlPanel();
        track1 = new myrace.Track();

        jLabel1.setText("jLabel1");

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(505, 325));
        setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(505, 325));
        setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(505, 325));
        setResizable(false);
        setSize(new java.awt.Dimension(505, 325));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(10, 10, 10)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(controlPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(track1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addContainerGap())))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(10, 10, 10)
                .addComponent(track1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(10, 10, 10)
                .addComponent(controlPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(10, 10, 10))
        );

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }                   

    public static void main(String args[]) {

       try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Race.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Race.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Race.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Race.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Race().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }


    private myrace.ControlPanel controlPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private myrace.Track track1;

}
```

Control Panel

```
package myrace;

public class ControlPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    public ControlPanel() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

    private void initComponents() {

        btnStart = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnReset = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnExit = new javax.swing.JButton();
        lblRed = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        txtRed = new javax.swing.JTextField();

        btnStart.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12)); 
        btnStart.setText("Start");
        btnStart.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(69, 23));
        btnStart.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(69, 23));
        btnStart.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(69, 23));
        btnStart.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnStartActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btnReset.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12)); 
        btnReset.setText("Reset");
        btnReset.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(69, 23));
        btnReset.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(69, 23));
        btnReset.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(69, 23));

        btnExit.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12)); 
        btnExit.setText("Exit");
        btnExit.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(69, 23));
        btnExit.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(69, 23));
        btnExit.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(69, 23));
        btnExit.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnExitActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        lblRed.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12)); 
        lblRed.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblRed.setText("Red");
        lblRed.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(75, 25));
        lblRed.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(75, 25));
        lblRed.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(75, 25));

        txtRed.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 12)); 
        txtRed.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(75, 25));
        txtRed.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(75, 25));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(85, 85, 85)
                            .addComponent(txtRed, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(85, 85, 85)
                            .addComponent(lblRed, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(119, 119, 119)
                        .addComponent(btnStart, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                        .addComponent(btnReset, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                        .addComponent(btnExit, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addGap(119, 119, 119))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(5, 5, 5)
                .addComponent(lblRed, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(txtRed, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(10, 10, 10)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(btnReset, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(btnExit, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(btnStart, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(5, 5, 5))
        );
    }                  

    private void btnStartActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        Track myTrack = new Track();
        Thread myThread = new Thread(myTrack);
        myThread.start();        
    }                                        

    private void btnExitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        System.exit(0);
    }                                       



    private javax.swing.JButton btnExit;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnReset;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnStart;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblRed;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtRed;


}
```

Comment: I don't see you calling the _first_ `run()` method.

Comment: Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of this disconnected snippet?

Comment: You don't call the run method. myThread.start90; takes care of that.

Comment: It doesn't show what pbRed is - would be good to see a bit more code.as @KevinWorkman said.

Comment: Working on MCVE to post...

Comment: I wrote an article, [Horse Race GUI](http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=425), that would be helpful to you.  Take a look and see how I wrote different model, view, and controller classes to keep my concerns separate and how I animated the horses.